# Mermaind plugin for PyCharm does not recognise "create participant"

Tags: pycharm, mermaid

The Mermaid plugin for PyCharm does not seem to allow the mid-sequence creation of classes.

When using the live mermaid editor with this code:

```
sequenceDiagram
    A ->> B: Hi B
    create participant C
    A ->> C: Hi C
```

I correctly get the following image[image: Mermaid Live Editor]

The same code in the PyCharm plugin I get error: `<signal type> or ID expected, got 'participant'`

```
...create participant C    A ->> C: Hi C
-----------------------^
Expecting 'SOLID_OPEN_ARROW', 'DOTTED_OPEN_ARROW', 'SOLID_ARROW', 'DOTTED_ARROW', 'SOLID_CROSS', 'DOTTED_CROSS', 'SOLID_POINT', 'DOTTED_POINT', got 'NEWLINE'
```

Is there a way around this?  I have not found references to the PyCharm plugin in relation to this issue with Mermaid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had been an issue but has now been resolved. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/MERMAID-115.